# IDEA always recompile all files even if they are never changed

Tags: intellij-idea

I use IDEA 2016 and I turn on "make project automatically" and use Eclipse compiler.After I change the code, I saw it says auto compile was complete and run it immediately,it shows errors that "can not found the class". Everytime I have to wait it for about 10s. And if you run it again it will recomple all files in the package even if they are never changed. It confuse me a lot.

Comment: Have to tried clear cache and restart from under the file menu?

Comment: I tried，but it doesn't work.